# calculate integral $\;2\int_{-2}^{0} \sqrt{8x+16}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to calculate the integral  $$2\int_{-2}^{0} \sqrt{8x+16}dx$$ The answer is $\;\dfrac {32}{6}\;$ but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: The answer with the multiple of $2$ is really supposed to be $32/6$? Everybody below gets $32/6$ without the multiple of $2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$I = F(x) = \int_{-2}^0 \sqrt{(8x + 16)}\,dx$$

We use substitution:

- Let $u = 8x + 16,\;\;du = 8\,dx \implies dx = \dfrac 18 du$

Change limits of integration:

- When $x = -2, u = 0$, when $x = 0, u = 16$.

Substituting equivalent expressions and changing the limits of integration then gives us:

$$\int_{-2}^0 \sqrt{(8x + 16)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{16} \sqrt{u}\,\left(\frac 18 du\right) = \dfrac 18 \int_0^{16} u^{1/2}\,du$$

Now we use the *power rule* to integrate: $\quad \int u^a\,du = \dfrac{u^{a + 1}}{a+1} + C,\quad\text{for all}\;a\neq -1$

We integrate with respect to $u$ and evaluate the result $I = F(u)$: $F(16) - F(0)$.

$$ \dfrac 18 \int_0^{16} u^{1/2}\,du = \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}\right)=\frac{1}{12}\left(u^{3/2}\right)\Bigg|^{16}_{0} = \frac{1}{12}\Bigl[(64) - (0)\Bigr] = \frac{32}{6}$$

---

If your integral was, as you write it, given as $2I = 2F(x) = 2F(u)$, then our result will be $$2\cdot \frac {32}{6} = \frac{32}{3}$$

Comment: I got an answer 256/3 when I used this method !

Comment: please vote up the question

Comment: @amWhy: so nicely written with all details +1

Answer (score 4):

Make the substitution, $y=8x+16$. This gives us $dx = dy/8$. Hence, the integral becomes
$$I=\int_0^{16}\sqrt{y} dy/8$$
I trust you can finish it from here, by recall the formula $\displaystyle\int y^n dy = \dfrac{y^{n+1}}{n+1} + \text{constant}$

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple $u$ substitution. Let $u = 8x + 16$. Then $du = 8dx$, and we have:

$$\int_{-2}^{0} \sqrt{8x+16}dx = \frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{16}u^{1/2}du = \frac{1}{8}[\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}|^{16}_{0}] = \frac{1}{12}[(64) - (0)] = \frac{32}{6}$$